USG is reporting 'Server Reject' while APs and PoE switches are 'Connected' to Unify Controller in Docker
My USG isn't correctly adopted by my Unify Controller running in docker.
My cloud key controller was failing so I moved the controller to a docker image on the home server (OpenSUSE) and most things are peachy. Except the USG has the following info status:
Model:       UniFi-Gateway-3
Version:     4.4.57.5578372
MAC Address: f0:9f:c2:c7:65:76
IP Address:  159.196.223.234
Hostname:    Gateway
Uptime:      9789306 seconds

Status:      Server Reject (http://172.16.69.11:8080/inform)

When an example of the hubs that work is:
Version:     7.0.50.15613
MAC Address: 18:e8:29:b8:ac:fb
IP Address:  172.16.69.214
Hostname:    BasementPoESwitch
Uptime:      2384594 seconds
NTP:         Synchronized

Status:      Connected (http://172.16.69.11:8080/inform)


That the other devices are fine makes me suspect the issue is with the USG, but I can't find an issue with it's configuration.

Final vain random thing I tried:
Factory reset USG (not the first of the evening)
Add IP in the correct range, but not the intended final IP of the USG
Adopt via set-announce
Apparently it can't configure a device that already has the right IP?!
